# Problems using Text Analytics

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

I'm using Sentiment Analysis by Azure, but since yesterday I'm receiving empty responses from the API, without any error code. I also cannot check my API usage on Azure Portal. Can you help me you figure it out?

Comment: Maybe you were using a trial license and it expired?

Comment: I'm using a free license (max 5.000 requests). But at Microsoft Azure Portal, I cannot see if I reached the limit! Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, nowadays you can actually see the number of transactions consumed from the Azure Portal.

1. Navigate to your Text Analytics Subscription in the Azure Portal
2. Select **Overview**
3. Under the Monitoring section of the Overview Page, you should see a Transactions graph. Click on the **Total Transactions** graph.
4. Now you can change the time period of the graph by:

   4.1 Click **Edit chart**

   4.2 Select desired **Time Range**

Luis Cabrera | Text Analytics Program Manager | Cloud AI Platform, Microsoft